# How does scanf() return EOF?

Tags: c, scanf, eof

If the following function returns an integer:

```
int scanf( const char *format, ... );
```

How does `scanf()` return `EOF`?

I have experimented with the two versions below:

// Why does this work?

```
int num;
int flag = scanf("%d", &num);

while(flag != EOF) {    
    flag = scanf("%d", &num);
}
```

// Versus this version?

```
int num;
scanf("%d", &num);

while(num != EOF) {
    scanf("%d", &num);
}
```

In other words, I'm confused why the `num` variable does not become `EOF` after `scanf("%d", &num);` but flag does become `EOF` after `int flag = scanf("%d", &num);`

Comment: Please read the man page, you'll see that `scanf` returns the *number of items successfully read* or `EOF` if there was a file error.

Comment: Because EOF is an integer that is **returned**... not read into a variable. You say it yourself in the question title: "how does scanf ***return*** EOF?". That seems pretty clear if you take a look at [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

Comment: Neither version works correctly in all cases, e.g., try inputting `abc` into the first version, or `-1` into the second… Overall reading directly from stdin with `scanf` is hard to get right, so it is usually recommended to first read a line with `fgets` and then parse than with `sscanf`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the argument of the scanf call that gets the value of EOF. It is the function returns EOF in case there is an error or end of file is encountered.

Pay attention to that arguments of scanf can have various types as for example be a pointer to first character of a character array.

So the second code snippet does not make sense.

From the function description in the C Standard

> 3 **The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
>   failure occurs** before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
>   Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items
>   assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
>   event of an early matching failure.

Answer (score 3):

Per [**7.21.6.4 The scanf function**, paragraph 3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.4p3) of the C standard:

> The scanf function **returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed**. Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

For example, the `stdin` input stream has been closed, or the end-of-file has been reached (if, for example, `stdin` was redirected from a file with `yourProgram < inputFile`).

Note that if you attempt to use `scanf()` to read more than one value, such as with `scanf("%d,%d",&a,&b);` and `scanf()` gets an error after reading `a` in this case, it will return `1` and not `EOF`.

Note that your code

```
while(flag != EOF) {    

    flag = scanf("%d", &num);
}
```

will go into an infinite loop should the next input be something that isn't an integer, such as `"This is text"`.  In that case, `scanf()` will return `0` and `"This is text"` will remain as the next input.